# SQLAlchemy: Dynamically loaded backreference to another module

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's suppose that I have a User model in one module.

```
class User(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Then I want to add a dynamically-loaded, many-to-one relationship towards User from a Post model in another module. Also, I don't want to 'pollute' the User's model definition with relationships from this other module.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this other than adding a field to the User class from outside of the Post model, like this?

```
class Post(Model):
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

User.posts = relationship('Post', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you can define it in the Post model (see below)

```
class Post(Model):
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship('User', backref=backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Comment: Oh, there is something weird going on... I first tried something very similar to this, but with backref stated in a slightly different way, as in "relationship('User', backref='posts', lazy='dynamic')". If I do it this way, I get an error (On relationship (whatever), 'dynamic' loaders cannot be used with many-to-one/one-to-one relationships and/or uselist=False. While, if I do it your way, it works perfectly. I wonder if this is a bug or is there a difference between the two approaches?

Comment: There is a huge difference: in one case *lazy* applies to one side of the relationship, while in the other - to the other side.